# Multi Device Hybrid Apps - Unable to launch Ripple - Chrome not found

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2013, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

After installing the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Preview) for Visual Studio CTP2 Extension in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 x64, I am unable to launch a new Multi-Device Hybrid App in Ripple.

Details:

- When Installing the Extension I chose not to install Chrome as it was already installed
- Opening the solution displays an error message

  ```
  We've detected issues with your system's environment configuration
  ```

  along with

  ```
  Google Chrome - The software is missing from your system.  You may have to configure it after installation.
  ```

  A link to the instructions is provided.
- On the [instruction page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx#ThirdParty) the link for chrome is simply to the [chrome install page](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/index.html)
- Chrome is already installed in

  ```
  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
  ```
- Attempting to launch the application with the **Ripple - Nexus (Galaxy)** setting causes the error

  ```
  Chrome must be installed in order to launch the app in Ripple
  ```
- I am able to launch the app on both the Android emulator and an Android device

What changes do I need to make to my configuration for the project to launch Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this issue because it is currently hard-coded to look for Chrome in
`%PROGRAMFILES%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`
but you have it installed in your Users folder.
To workaround this, please re-install Chrome to your %Program Files% folder.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome worked.  Note: It installed to the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` path, not `%ProgramFiles%`.  Before reinstalling, I attempted to workaround the issue by creating a junction to the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` path from the install folder in users - this falled.  Also, I tried a manual copy for the files to  to the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` path - this also failed.  A full uninstall/reinstall was required.